# Update Table using laravel 8, the data never updated into table

Tags: laravel

Updating Table using laravel 8, the data never updated into the table but the return redirect()->route('reviewSteps') is worked correctly, it ignores the updating code
i made model and view and i do not use middleware
what should i do?

```
    public function update(Request $request, Task $tasks): \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'user_id',
        'taskStartBy' => 'required',
        'taskSentTo' => 'required',
        'frequency' => 'required',
        'importance' => 'required',
        'confirmation' => 'required',
        'confirmOther',
        'withSLA' => 'required',
        'involveShare' => 'required',
        'sharedFile',
        'fileType',
        'otherFileType',
        'fileUse',
        'portal',
        'portalName',
        'receiveReport' => 'required',
        'role',
        'reportName',
        'roleSendReport',
        'reportSample',
        'reportScope',
        'reportNameTwo',
        'roleSendReportTwo',
        'reportSampleTwo',
        'reportScopeTwo',
        ]);

    $tasks->update([
        $tasks->taskStartBy = $request->input('taskStartBy'),
        $tasks->taskSentTo = $request->input('taskSentTo'),
        $tasks->frequency = $request->input('frequency'),
        $tasks->importance = $request->input('importance'),
        $tasks->confirmation = $request->input('confirmation'),
        $tasks->confirmOther = $request->input('confirmOther'),
        $tasks->withSLA = $request->input('withSLA'),
        $tasks->involveShare = $request->input('involveShare'),
        $tasks->sharedFile = $request->input('sharedFile'),
        $tasks->fileType = $request->input('fileType'),
        $tasks->otherFileType = $request->input('otherFileType'),
        $tasks->fileUse = $request->input('fileUse'),
        $tasks->portal = $request->input('portal'),
        $tasks->portalName = $request->input('portalName'),
        $tasks->receiveReport = $request->input('receiveReport'),
        $tasks->role = $request->input('role'),
        $tasks->reportName = $request->input('reportName'),
        $tasks->roleSendReport = $request->input('roleSendReport'),
        $tasks->reportSample = $request->input('reportSample'),
        $tasks->reportScope = $request->input('reportScope'),
        $tasks->reportNameTwo = $request->input('reportNameTwo'),
        $tasks->roleSendReportTwo = $request->input('roleSendReportTwo'),
        $tasks->reportSampleTwo = $request->input('reportSampleTwo'),
        $tasks->reportScopeTwo = $request->input('reportScopeTwo'),
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('reviewSteps');
}
```

Comment: Check your model. Does all of this fields marked as ```fillable```? Check the link [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) for more information.

Comment: Check if the fields are fillable in your model. This is probably the issue.

Comment: yes, all of this fields marked as fillable

Answer (score 0):

The update method should be like this:

```php
$tasks->update([
        'taskStartBy' => $request->input('taskStartBy'),
        'taskSentTo' => $request->input('taskSentTo'),
        'frequency' => $request->input('frequency'),
        'importance' => $request->input('importance'),
    .
    .
    . and so on ...
```

If you’re going to use "Mass Assignment" you should add all of these fields to the Model:

```php
    protected $fillable = ['taskStartBy', 'taskSentTo', 'frequency', ...etc ];
```

or you can turn this off with:

```php
    protected $guarded = [];
```

check this part of the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: okay, I will try this now

Comment: its also does not work\

Comment: can you add `dd($tasks)` before `$tasks->update([ ...` to check that it passes the validation .. if it redirects back and not show the dd then it means there is issue in the validations

Comment: ikay i will do that

Comment: i made that and give me the following message

App\Models\Task {#1280 ▼
  #table: "tasks"
  #fillable: array:29 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []]